# react-navigation useLinkTo outside screen but inside NavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am surprised that `useLinkTo` and the like (`useNavigation`) can only be used inside a Navigator Screen when all they really should need is the navigation context set-up by the `NavigationContainer`.

Because my scenario is a notification system that wraps the whole app whose notifications should be able to link to other parts in the app.

```
<NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
  <Notifications>
    <RootStack/>
  </Notifications>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Now that it sits outside the `RootStack` hooks like `useLinkTo`, `useNavigation` do not work and complain about a missing context:

> "Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?"

Is there a work-around for deep linking using the bare bone NavigationContainer (ref) maybe?

I tried to move the `Notifications` provider inside `RootStack` but that does not help.

Comment: Did you try using `withNavigation`? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/with-navigation/

Comment: no, because I am using v5 not v1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the documentation, there is a way mentioned for achieving this for `useNavigation`, i.e [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop).

Basically, what we do is assign the navigation container to an external ref, and then use that ref to navigate while outside the `RootStack`.

In file `/project/Navigation/RootNavigation.js`

```js
import { createRef } from 'react';

export const navigationRef = createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

export function goBack() {
  navigationRef.current?.goBack();
}

export default useRootNavigation = () => ({ navigationRef, navigate, goBack });
```

Edit: More functions for ref can be found here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container

Then in your code,

```js
import {navigationRef} from '/project/Navigation/RootNavigation';

<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} linking={linking}>
  <Notifications>
    <RootStack/>
  </Notifications>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then, you can import the `useRootNavigation` hook in your Notification component to navigate, goback.
For better explanation, you can refer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop.

However, this is not possible for `useLinkTo` currently I guess.
I'm too searching for a way to use `useLinkTo` like this. If anyone finds it, please let me know!

**Edit2:**

For replicating the behavior of `useLinkTo`, I implemented the following by referring to source code for `useLinkTo`:

In file `/project/Navigation/RootNavigation.js`

```js
import { getActionFromState, getStateFromPath } from '@react-navigation/native';

/**
* Previous code
*/

export function dispatch(action) {
  navigationRef.current?.dispatch(action);
}

export function linkTo(path, config = null) {
  var state = getStateFromPath(path, config);
  var action = getActionFromState(state);
  if (action !== undefined) {
    dispatch(action);
  }
}

export default useRootNavigation = () => ({
  navigationRef,
  navigate,
  goBack,
  dispatch,
  linkTo,
});
```

Then, wherever we need to use useLinkTo, outside the navigation

```js
  const navigation = useRootNavigation(); // The hook defined in RootNavigation.js

  someFunction(()=>{
    navigation.linkTo(path, linking.config);
  })
```

In your(mine as well) case, we'll have to specify the linking config, or the default behavior of deep linking will be used.

Comment: thanks! I see the default linkTo does a bit more traversing up the link tree when creating the navigation action. You sure your code works as expected?

Comment: @philk yes, it did work for me, and it should work as expected, as the ref used is the root of all navigatiors; thus removing need for traversing up.

Comment: also, the above `linkTo` code doesn't handle invalid paths, so i guess we need to implement that too if needed.